# How to get related value between two dataframes

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

If I have two dataframes. Dataframe A have an a_id column, dataframe B have an b_id column and a b_value column. How can I join A and B on a_id = b_id and get C with id and max(b_value)?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQKEr.png)

Comment: Take a look at  the [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) / `merge` and `combine` functions

Answer (score 0):

you can use the concat function in pandas to append either columns or rows from one DataFrame to another.
heres an example:

```
# Read in first 10 lines of surveys table
survey_sub = surveys_df.head(10)
# Grab the last 10 rows
survey_sub_last10 = surveys_df.tail(10)
# Reset the index values to the second dataframe appends properly
survey_sub_last10 = survey_sub_last10.reset_index(drop=True)
# drop=True option avoids adding new index column with old index values
```

When i concatenate DataFrames, i need to specify the axis. axis=0 tells pandas to stack the second DataFrame UNDER the first one. It will automatically detect whether the column names are the same and will stack accordingly. axis=1 will stack the columns in the second DataFrame to the RIGHT of the first DataFrame. To stack the data vertically, i need to make sure we have the same columns and associated column format in both datasets. When i stack horizontally, i want to make sure what i am doing makes sense (i.e. the data are related in some way).